# Permission denied MySQL

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

Why am I denied access and how can I fix it? I googled a lot but still couldn't find the answer

> zsh: permission denied: /usr/local/mysql

Comment: `/usr/local/mysql` is probably a directory, not an executable. You probably want `/usr/local/bin/mysql`

Comment: zsh file permissions ?

Comment: @Batuhan I am trying to write my first database and am getting confused about the rudimentary.

Comment: Try this, `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc` and after that, `source ~/.zshrc` in zsh. It will add mysql executable to your terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you haven't created yet new users, and if im right both mariadb and mysql start with only two users with an "invalid" password allowing you to get access only from local.. try "sudo mysql", you should be logged in as the mysql root user and be able to create new standard users